# Griddb procedure call to export data

Tags: export, procedure, griddb

How to write a procedure to export data periodically mostly schedule based like every 1st Saturday of the month from griddb and save data into cloud storage like S3.

The objective is to export set of data like monthly sensor readings for periodic calculations which can be later used for data analysis.